# Change Wordpress Admin URL For The Core Function

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Can I check if there is a way to force a URL for certain functionality in the wordpress admin panel? The problem is, some functionality starts to break as it points to the wrong url ( points to the root domain)

The URL of wordpress is `www.domain.com/subdirectory/` but the files are in the root directory (configures reverse proxy)

Some functionality like search post and log in starts to break (redirected to error 404 page in the root directory - e.g point to domain.com/wp-admin when it should be domain.com/app/wp-admin). it look up for www.domain.com instead of `www.domain.com/subdirectory/`

Note that in the database, I have already change the database site url to `www.domain.com/subdirectory`.

Comment: maybe you can rephrase stuffs to make it a bit clearer. anyway, does the core files of wordpress reside in `www.domain.com/subdirectory/`?

Comment: It resides in www.domain.com but the url is www.domain.com/app/ due to reverse proxy.